# List all possible switch cases?

Tags: c#, console-application

Im making a console app and it works great but for some parts of it theres switch cases, I would like to make a

```
case "help":
    //List all cases here without Console.WriteLine("Option, Option, Option")
```

I have tried googling this and so far turned no results, If i print the value of the switch it returns Help :/

Comment: Are you asking for `default:`?

Comment: Whart do you mean by "List all cases here without Console.WriteLine("Option, Option, Option")"?

Comment: Its ok dude the answer below works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this with `CommandLineParser` from https://commandline.codeplex.com/.

For example:

```
    class Options
    {
        [Option("account-name", Required = true, HelpText = "Name of the account to use")]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }

        [Option("single-file", HelpText = "Use one file as output")]
        public bool SingleFile { get; set; }

        [Option("excel-timestamps", DefaultValue = false, HelpText = "If set, timestamps will be printed with no timezone information in a format recognisable by Excel")]
        public bool ExcelTimestamps { get; set; }

        [ParserState]
        public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

        [HelpOption]
        public string GetUsage()
        {
            return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
              (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
        }
    }
```

Then in `Main`

```
static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var options = new Options();
            if (!Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options))
            {
                options.GetUsage();//Prints to console

                (...)
```